Cassandra restore to K8ssandra using Medusa but does not create MedusaBackup resource
Working on moving our current EC2 based Cassandra clusters to Kubernetes K8ssandra, as well as some disaster recovery testing.  We have Medusa doing our backups on a regular basis saving to S3, which is accessible to our K8ssandra deployment.
When creating a MedusaTask sync operation resource for K8ssandra, Medusa reads the manifest.json files from S3, but never creates the MedusaBackup resource object from which we can do the restore.
Both cluster names are identical; Both clusters are at Cassandra v4.1.5. K8ssandra-operator is v1.18.0; Medusa 0.22.0.  I'm thinking this is partly due to naming conventions which are not compatible between clusters.  Our EC2 based cluster is

Cluster name: testcluster-a
Datacenter: DC1
Racks: 1, 2, 1 for Test Environment; Our main environment has racks 1, 2, 3

(due to our restricted test topology we have 2 nodes in one rack, not my design)



Due to Kubernetes / K8ssandra naming conventions of size and capitalization, we have to use:

Cluster name: testcluster-a
Datacenter: dc1
Racks: rack1, rack2, rack3

# Source: k8ssandra-clusters/templates/k8ssandra-cluster.yaml
apiVersion: k8ssandra.io/v1alpha1
kind: K8ssandraCluster
metadata:
  namespace: k8ssandra-operator
  name: testcluster-a
spec:
  cassandra:
    metadata:
    datacenters:
      - metadata:
          name: dc3
        size: 3
        racks:
          - name: rack1
          - name: rack2
          - name: rack3

From the Medusa logs, it shows it reading the backup schema.cql one nodes' tokenmap JSON, then all nodes manifest.json file, then disconnects from S3.  So, Medusa can read the backup files, just doesn't seem to be doing anything with them.
One thing I have tried with a test backup is update the tokenmap files to change the names of the racks and datacenters to what is in our K8ssandra cluster, but still getting the same results.  Was hoping that might aligning the names would help, or at least get something else which may be useful in the logs.

Kind of proved that it is a naming conflict.  Was able to create a Cassandra cluster and a K8ssandra Cluster in a sandbox environment, named the same for datacenter and racks.  Was able to complete a backup from EC2 Cassandra to K8ssandra without much issue.
Now, to figure out how to get a around that and make the backups works on the K8ssandra clusters.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Based on the description you supplied, it appears that you are attempting to clone an EC2-based cluster to a K8ssandra cluster that doesn't have an identical topology.
You won't be able to do a straightforward clone using Medusa in K8ssandra since the configuration of the source cluster is different.
As an alternative, you can try a restore-cluster of the source backup and supply a list of 2-3 nodes in the destination cluster with --seed-target. This method will use sstableloader to bulk load the snapshots to K8ssandra cluster and doesn't require the topology to be identical.
For additional info, see the Cassandra Medusa docs on Restoring a full cluster. Cheers!
